# Deleting non-duplicate dictionaries containing a duplicate field from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I obtain a list of more than 100000 items from the database some of which are duplicate based on a unique ID.

Returned data is similar to below:

```
my_list = [
    {"id_str": "foo", "field1": "foobar", "field2":...},
    {"id_str": "foo", "field2": "foobaz", "field2":...},
    {"id_str": "bar", "field1": "bazfoo", "field2":...},
    {"id_str": "baz", "field1": "barbaz", "field2":...},
    ...
    ]
```

As you see, the whole dictionary in the list is not necessarily duplicate to another dictionary while `id_str` is duplicate.

I am currently using below simple method to eliminate the items having same `id_str` value:

```
collected_ids = []
cleaned_list = []
for item in my_list:
    if(item["id_str"] not in collected_ids):
        collected_ids.append(item["id_str"])
        cleaned_list.append(item)
```

However, this takes rather long for hundreds of thousands items in a list. Is there more efficient way do to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *itertools.groupby* and then take only `list(g)[0]` for each group, if its not important which one of the duplicates you take

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [
    {"id_str": "foo", "field1": "foobar", "field2":...},
    {"id_str": "bar", "field1": "bazfoo", "field2":...},
    {"id_str": "baz", "field1": "barbaz", "field2":...},
    {"id_str": "foo", "field2": "foobaz", "field2":...},
]

new = []
l = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x['id_str'])
for k, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x['id_str']):
    new.append(list(g)[0])

print(new)
# [{'id_str': 'bar', 'field1': 'bazfoo', 'field2': Ellipsis}, {'id_str': 'baz', 'field1': 'barbaz', 'field2': Ellipsis}, {'id_str': 'foo', 'field1': 'foobar', 'field2': Ellipsis}]
```